# Вопросы по Model/View Programming в Qt

Tags: виджет, qt

У меня есть виджет QListView и список строк QStringList. Делаю так:

```
QStringListModel m_stringListModel;
QStringList m_newWords;
QListView listView_words;
listView_words->setModel(&m_stringListModel);
m_stringListModel.setStringList(newWords);
```

1) Я бы хотел, чтобы когда изменялся текст в одном из элементе списка QListView, то так же бы изменялся текст в объекте newWords.
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы model и view как-то сами это делали или это надо делать в ручную?
Если в ручную, то это надо делать через сигналы и слоты? Я не смог найти подходящий сигнал от класса QListView. В нем нет сигналов на изменение текста. Может я не там искал?

2) Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатие правой кнопки мыши по элементу списка QListView удалялся этот элемент? В QListView есть только сигнал clicked, который реагирует на левую кнопку мыши. 
Как это можно сделать для правой кнопки мыши? Переопределить событие void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Правильный способ - держать модель `QStringListModel` и организовывать общение с ней путем вызова [геттера `stringList()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qstringlistmodel.html#stringList)
- Если я правильно понимаю, то отловить щелчок правой кнопкой мыши можно с помощью сигнала [`customContextMenuRequested.`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) Схожий вариант заключается [в использовании `event filters.`](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Handling_right_button_clicks_using_Qt)

> - Переопределять `mousePressEvent / mouseReleaseEvent` лично я бы не стал, поскольку можно столкнуться с большим количеством подводных камней типа случая, если пользователь зажал правую кнопку мыши, а после этого сделал `drag` за пределы клиентской области вашего приложения.
> - Хотя, возможно, достаточно будет просто удалять элемент в ответ на `mouseReleaseEvent.`

Comment: По первому пункту понятно. Спасибо.
Не получается сделать удаление через customContextMenuRequested. Делаю так: 

    listView_words->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu); 
    QObject::connect(listView_words,
  SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint& pos)), SLOT(foo(const QPoint& pos)));

Поставил на слот точку останова. Запустил программу, нажал ПКМ по виджету QListView, но в слот так и не попал.